# Scroll without using arrow keys or mouse in Gmail with shortcuts on?

Tags: gmail, keyboard-shortcuts

I do not want to have my hands leave the traditional typing position to navigate Gmail via shortcuts. I can do everything I need to do except scroll through really long e-mails. For that it requires my right hand drop down to navigate the arrow keys on my keyboard, which are off to the side. This is annoying.

Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

My page up and down keys are also off to the side.

Comment: what OS are you using? This sounds like more of a browser/OS specific question as I can't find anything scroll related in the [Gmail Keyboard Shortcuts](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=6594) page.

Comment: I'm using osX and Chrome. Now that you brought that up, I wonder if a vim keyboard shortcut plugin might work.

Answer (score 11):

Scrolling up and down a page isn't a GMail-specific shortcut but the browser/OS default. You can use <kbd>Space bar</kbd> to scroll down, and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Space bar</kbd> to scroll up.

If the conversation has multiple long messages, you can use <kbd>N</kbd> & <kbd>P</kbd> to jump to the beginning of the later/earlier message respectively.

Comment: +1 I stopped using space a while ago because too many websites autofocus on a field somewhere on the page (like google's search results page or Yahoo's any page). But I confirmed this on gmail... maybe I'll start using it again.

Comment: This works, but it isn't as smooth as the up/down error. I rarely scroll back up, so this is acceptable for now. Thanks!

Comment: There is an equivalent to scroll up - just use 'shift-space', much like you'd use shift-tab to go backward through the elements in a form.  However, [an_ant](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/12881/an-ant) has mentioned  in a bounty notice that the scrolling done by the spacebar is too large for their preferences, do you know of any alternatives or ways to modify this behavior?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [this UserScript](https://userscripts.org/scripts/show/43440) that adjusts the amount of scrolling that takes place when pressing the <kbd>Space bar</kbd>.

If you have JavaScript experience, you could also [write](https://userscripts.org/guides/46) [your own UserScript](https://userscripts.org/guides/22) for you browser to use specific keys to scroll up and down.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>spacebar</kbd> will do the trick.
I often use <kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd> for navigating between newer/older conversation.
<kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>p</kbd> for moving between messages.
You can see all the shortcuts by pressing <kbd>?</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Using the <kbd>spacebar</kbd> to scroll down and <kbd>tab</kbd>-<kbd>spacebar</kbd> is pretty much the only portable way to scroll in a browser. Make sure that the focus is not on an entry like a check box, text box, or button, and then push space - tada!  The page scrolls until the last couple lines at the bottom of the screen are at the top.

If you prefer to scroll a few lines at a time, instead of in big chunks like this, you'll want to add key handlers for <kbd>spacebar</kbd> and <kbd>tab</kbd>-<kbd>spacebar</kbd>.  Something like:

```
window.onkeydown = function(e){ 
    if (e.keyCode == 32){            // If spacebar keycode
        if (event.shiftKey) {        // If shift is being held
            window.scrollBy(0, -50); // Scroll over 0 pixels and up 50 pixels 
        } else {                     // Otherwise
            window.scrollBy(0, 50);  // Scroll over 0 pixels and down 50 pixels 
        }
    }
};
```

would do this if you stick it into an extension.  If you want this prepackaged, there are a few keyboard shortcut managers such as [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mgjjeipcdnnjhgodgjpfkffcejoljijf?hl=en) that would do the job.